# Unable to format pen drive

Tags: usb, usb-drive, format

These are the errors i am facing.
 I have tried gparted and disks.

**Gparted error:**

```
Input/output error during write on /dev/sdc
```

**Error formatting volume**

```
Error wiping device: Command-line `wipefs -a "/dev/sdc1"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: wipefs: error: /dev/sdc1: probing initialization failed: Device or resource busy
 (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

**Unable to access “6.2 GB Volume”**

```
Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at /media/s/e1564750-3802-4dbb-8df8-d1bdff3f6a93:
Command-line `mount -t "ext4" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sdc1" "/media/s/e1564750-3802-4dbb-8df8-d1bdff3f6a93"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: 
wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
dmesg | tail or so.
```

Comment: There is a long-standing bug around with wipefs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/util-linux/+bug/1059872 --- maybe this is the case. Or the drive is failing,

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you may have a broken pendrive; go to a terminal and try these commands; ensure the pendrive is in fact /dev/sdc 1st though (use `mount`):

```
sudo -i
fdisk /dev/sdc
p # Lists the partitions
d # This deletes the partition. Again, be careful you have the right one!
p # check...
n # Create a new partition
b # This one isn't a command, it's a type selection - vfat
w # Save changes
```

This *should* give you a list of partitions; delete the only one there (if more, repeat 'd' until there aren't - whilst being careful that this *is definitely the right drive*! It should then create a new one, set it to FAT32, and write it.

If that works, type `fdisk -t vfat /dev/sdc1 ; exit` & you're done.

If not, try `cat /dev/zero >/dev/sdc` & let it run for a while (-c when bored..) - if it generates no errors, try step 1 again. If you still get I/O errors, it's damaged.

Comment: This is correct, but I think you should comment what each `fdisk` command is doing and the expected results. If the OP get something wrong it can trash the system...

Comment: That's what the following paragraph is? p=list, d=delete, etc.. there are two warnings in the answer about getting the right drive; & it's not going to be easy to trash the system if it IS the right drive.... I could do it as comments line-by-line, by I always find that distracts from the flow.

Comment: I got `b: unknown command` then `Re-reading the partition table failed.: Device or resource busy`

Comment: b isn't a command, it's the 'vfat' partitoin type - n command should've given you options

Comment: @NicolasRaoul same here, but I did delete partition (d), then write (w), then tried GUI to format it as fat and it was successful