# Error whilst creating partition

Tags: partitioning, disk, gnome-disk-utility

Original error message in german

```
Error wiping newly created partition /dev/sdc1: Command-line `wipefs -a "/dev/sdc1"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: wipefs: Fehler: /dev/sdc1: Initialisierung der Suche ist gescheitert: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
 (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

Translated

```
Error wiping newly created partition /dev/sdc1: Command-line `wipefs -a "/dev/sdc1"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: wipefs: Error: /dev/sdc1: Initialation of search failed. File or directory not found
 (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

Does anyone know this error? And what does it mean?

Comment: This might help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/574328/unable-to-format-pen-drive. There seems to exist a bug also: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/1442840

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I know of at this time is to run the wipefs command manually and then format it again in gnome-disk-utility

[root]# wipefs -a /dev/sdc1